# Problems with ASP.Net Membership and Entity Framework Migrations using .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4, membership, visual-studio-2012

I am learning the migrations feature available in Entity Framework and I seem to hit a problem. When using an internet application project template and enabled entity framework migrations etc. I am trying to just create a default user onto the database - using an automatic migration:

```
protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb context)
{            
   WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", false);

    if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("ahicks2"))
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateAccount("ahicks2", "password", requireConfirmationToken:true);
    }

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    }
}
```

When I run "Update-Database -verbose" in the package manager I get the following error:

> Running Seed method.
>   System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException: The Provider encountered an unknown error.
>
> at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(String
>   userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)

The next line in the stack trace is the `Configuration.Seed` call. In my web config I am using the following setting for the membership provider to guarantee the tables are created in the database I want:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
```

The database tables are being created correctly, but the code falls over on the create user. Can anyone help? I'm sure its something simple. I wanted to test out these features - of course a simple answer is to revert back to using membership providers from asp.net 2.0! but I wanted to try and get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: By the way I've tried this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1598261.aspx/1 and it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Can you create a user directly in VisualStudio?

Comment: If you are referring to running the project and creating a new user of the base template. No I get the same exception. Just a different method call.

Comment: Did you run the prep program apsnetregsql.exe?   That might not be the exact name but something like it.

Comment: No that just registers the relevant tables to the database. The EF code first creates the necessary tables based either on default settings or configuration the first time you use the web security code. I don't even get that far - it fails when it tries to use the default membership provider because it thinks it doesn't extend the extendedmembershipprovider which is part of the WebMatrix.WebData assembly.

Comment: Here is a link that has seeding of users, roles and associating the two with EF5 CodeFirst [http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/)

Answer (score 5):

The answer lies on the surface.
Take a look at the MSDN page regarding this method:
[WebSecurity.CreateAccount Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createaccount%28v=vs.111%29)

*It presumes that matching user information (represented by userName) already exists in the user profile table. (To create a new user in both the membership table and in the user profile table, use the CreateUserAndAccount(String, String, Object, Boolean) method.)*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("YOURUSERNAME", "YOURPASSWORD");
```

You mght also wish to consider making sure the controller/class has

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

I'm trying to do a similar thing as you and struggling!

I'm failing with creating a role.

Dan.